# How to update a specific value in List<Class>?

Tags: java, android

I need to update one data in my `List<Cards>`. Class Cards looks like this:

```
public class Cards implements Comparable<Cards>{
private int cardImage, cardID, cardScore;

public Cards(int cardImage, int cardID, int cardScore){
    this.cardImage = cardImage;
    this.cardID = cardID;
    this.cardScore = cardScore;
}
public int getImage(){
    return cardImage;
}
public int getId(){
    return cardID;
}
public int getScore(){return cardScore;}

@Override
public int compareTo(Cards o) {
    return this.cardID > o.cardID ? 1 : (this.cardID < o.cardID ? -1 : 0);
}
```

In my MainActivity clas I initiated List `cardsList = new ArrayList<>();` and filled it like this

```
                for (i = 0; i < lvl; i++) {
                cardsList.add(new Cards(Constants.imageNumber[drawCard[i]], drawId[i], cardScore[i]));
            }
```

Now I want to update values only for `cardScore[i]`. How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by `cardScore[i]`?

Comment: My List has 3 variables in row.  cardScore[i] is the last one

Comment: Your Cards class has private fields and not set methods, so you can't update the values. Add a set or update method to Cards; then find the card you want at cardsList.get(index) and call that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create setters for your `Cards` class, then you can call those setters after using [`List#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) to get the card at a specific index.

```java
public class Cards implements Comparable<Cards>{
    // other methods omitted for brevity...
    public void setCardScore(int cardScore){
        this.cardScore = cardScore;
    }
}
// Usage:
cardsList.get(i).setCardScore(newCardScore);
```